# Cannot edit value in regedit on windows to fix broken VirtualBox Installation

Tags: virtualbox, windows-registry

I cannot install VirtualBox, tells me something like 'no drive F:', so I check it in the registry editor and see that install dir is 'F:\VM\', so I wanted to change it to 'C:\VM\' or delete it, but neither is possible. `cannot delete virtualbox: error while deleting key` and `Cannot edit InstallDir: Error writing the value's new Constant`. The 4 keys in the VirtualBox Key are (Default) which is (value not set), InstallDir which is as said above, Version and VersionExt which both are 5.2.20.

I tried everything I could think of, what else can I do to fix this? The endgoal btw is installing VirtualBox, those are just the suggested fixes for the different solutions I came to.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons I never am Admin on my account, and I did not realise I needed Admin privelages, because it didn't tell me. I right clicked>opened as admin and everything worked again and is now installing